# MySQL Connector appending the enum with the value one less than the actual one

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using the [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) for .NET to manage a MySQL database from C#.

When I try to insert an enum into the database it appends the enum with the value **one less than the actual** one.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue, SecondValue, ThirdValue;
}

public void InsertEnum() {
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    string sql = "INSERT INTO table (Col1) VALUES (@enumVal);";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enumVal", MyEnum.SecondValue);
        //Note I'm trying to insert 'SecondValue' --^

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

This inserts `FirstValue` in the database.

The `Col1` column, in the database, is of the ENUM datatype:

```
ENUM('FirstValue','SecondValue','ThirdValue')
```

If I try to append `MyEnum.FirstValue` I get a data truncation error (`data truncated for column COLUMN_NAME`) since it tries to use the same index as .NET (`0` in the case of `MyEnum.FirstValue`), which is a reserved value in [MySQL Enums](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-indexes) (since they start on `1` by default).

A solution is to append `+1` to all enum values or possibly make an extension:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enumVal", MyEnum.SecondValue + 1);
```

It still feels wrong to me that I have to modify the value manually, to a library that is supposed to convert it automatically.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there no default way to deal with this?

Comment: What is the datatype of col1 in the table?

Comment: Are you sure your enums are exactly as what you have given and you have not used specific int values inside enum declaration?

Comment: @MilindThakkar `ENUM('FirstValue','SecondValue','ThirdValue')`

Comment: @nawfal, are you asking if I wrote e.g. `FirstValue = -1` etc.? In that case, no, I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET enumerations are by default zero-based, and backed with an integer (i.e. you can cast a default enumeration to an integer and back).

I imagine what is happening is that the MySQL database driver is casting the enum value to an integer, and trying to insert that.

MySQL treats integers being inserted into enumeration columns as a 1-based index.

I would suggest just making the database column an integer instead of a MySQL enumeration. This way, zero is a valid value.

Alternatively, you could declare the first value of your enumeration to have an integer value of one, to match MySQL, like this:

```
public enum MyEnum 
{
    FirstValue = 1, 
    SecondValue, 
    ThirdValue
}
```

I think I'm right in saying that `SecondValue` and `ThirdValue` would then be backed with values 2 and 3 respectively.

Then when the connector casts the enumeration to an integer, it will return 1, 2, and 3, which would match what MySQL expects.

The third alternative is to keep the types as-is at both ends, and just make this mapping a function of your data layer (you do have one, right?) - then you only need to deal with this in one place. Could be a little misleading for future developers, mind.

Comment: I was considering your first and third alternative before asking this, but it still seems weird to me that this is needed in the first place. I mean, if MySQL made their own connector library dedicated for .NET, why not convert enums correctly?

Comment: Because MySQL enumerations and .NET enumerations are not analogous. `MyEnum.FirstValue` is just a fancy way of expressing literally `0` (or `1`, if that's how you've defined the enumeration). MySQL enumerations are string literals, by the looks of the documentation. There would be no way to map between the two that would be correct for every case.

Comment: But then I don't understand how passing `MyEnum.ThirdValue` works, since that is `2` turning into `3`, making it an invalid value for .NET but is correctly applied to the database as `ThirdValue`. To my understanding, the MySQLConnector must be mapping the enum int value.

Comment: A closer reading of the documentation implies that `...VALUES (@enumVal)` with `...AddWithValue("@enumVal", MyEnum.SecondValue);` is inserting an integer (not a string) into that field. The documentation states "*If the quotation marks are omitted, the number is regarded as an index*", then "*Values from the list of permissible elements in the column specification are numbered beginning with 1*". So I'd say this is performing as expected.

Comment: You could say that, if the int value is valued higher than the default behavior. I'm guessing the MySQL Connector must know that the [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) of the enum is [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), then I don't understand why they at least have a flag property to map default values to default values. I'm aware that MySQL enums starts with `1`, and .NET starts with `0` by default, but I can't see why it shouldn't at least map those together by default.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think that? Given that the MySQL Connector for .NET is only dealing with that respective connection I fail to see why it is created this way. I would understand it if the input was integers and it would map to the value MySQL desired it to be, but in this case it knows that is mapping a .NET enum to a MySQL enum value.

Comment: But MySQL has no way of knowing if the default was applied at the other end.  MySQL has no way of knowing if you might connect from a different framework in the future.  MySQL has no control if the convention of a language might change in the future.

Comment: @AskeB. Thinking it through, while it would be possible for `AddWithValue` to special case where the value is `System.Enum`, and insert either by index (`Convert.ToInt64(System.Enum e) + 1`) or by name ("\"" + System.Enum.ToString() + "\""`), the problem is that triggering this behaviour relies on knowing whether the database column is actually a MySQL enumeration or just a plan old integer column ahead of time (not possible). Otherwise, the default behaviour would be incorrect (either inserting an off-by-one value, or trying to insert a string into an integer column).

Comment: @Blam I don't get what you're saying. The MySQL Connector/NET is specifically for the connection between .NET and MySQL and that will not change. Perhaps the standards for either of them could change, but then they would just have to change the connector either way.
@ tomfanning Ah, you're right, I didn't think of the fact that a .NET enumeration value could be inserted into a number-value-column as well. Thanks for explaining that. Then I agree that it is expected behavior.

Comment: @AskeB. I guess as well that we have to remember that this stuff implements IDbConnection and IDbCommand, and callers of these interfaces may well not know what's behind them - so expected behaviour must be preserved. Anyway, hope my answer helped. Please accept if so.

Comment: @tomfanning I don't understand that point. If you made an adapter-client implementation to IDbCommand, I would still be surprised that default enumerations suddenly don't work when working with MySQL, so "expected" is perhaps more subjective. Another thing though; I don't really like that you're begging for acceptance of an answer. To my knowledge, accepting an answer means that it is the best actual solution to the asker's problem, not that it helped out a bit. I'm still giving it though since you made some effort explaining your view on why you don't expect it to behave the same way as I do.

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation off hand but the "general expectation" about what happens when you pass a .NET enumeration value into the Parameters collection on IDbCommand is that it is passed to the database as an integral value, since that is precisely what a .NET enumeration is. Many other RDBMS don't have the concept of an enumeration at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your enum like this

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue = 1, 
    SecondValue, 
    ThirdValue
}
```

It will start from 1 instead from 0.

Comment: But then I would have to do that for all enums that I use, right?

Comment: @AskeB. Yes but you won't be needing to add 1 or remove 1 when storing to or fetching from the database. Other alternative is just to use int values in the database *which Enum effectively is.